# java thrift client with embedded hive?

Tags: java, hive, thrift

According to the link here https://cwiki.apache.org/Hive/hiveclient.html#HiveClient-ThriftJavaClient. It says that

> Thrift Java Client 
>   Operates both in embedded mode and on standalone
>   server.

How do I run the thrift java client with hive in embedded mode?

Answer (score 2):

So here is how to run hive 'thrift' client in embedded mode.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.service.HiveInterface;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.service.HiveServer;
...
HiveInterface hiveClient = new HiveServer.HiveServerHandler();
```

Add following to classpath

$HIVE_HOME/lib/*.jar

$HIVE_HOME/conf

I found this in the hive source code here $HIVE_HOME/src/jdbc/src/java/../HiveConnection.java

Answer (score 0):

Hive use Thrift as RPC framework, and thrift rpc make it easy to "Operates both in embedded mode and on standalone server".

### Client Mode (connect to a standalone server)

```
    HiveConf hiveConf = new HiveConf();
    hiveConf.addResource("/Users/tzp/pppathh/hive-site.xml");

    TTransport transport = new TSocket("127.0.0.1", 10000);
    transport = PlainSaslHelper.getPlainTransport(USERNAME, PASSWORD, transport);
    TBinaryProtocol protocol = new TBinaryProtocol(transport);
    transport.open();

    ThriftCLIServiceClient cliServiceClient = new ThriftCLIServiceClient(new TCLIService.Client(protocol), hiveConf);
    SessionHandle sessionHandle = cliServiceClient.openSession(USERNAME, PASSWORD);

    OperationHandle operationHandle = cliServiceClient.executeStatement(sessionHandle, "select * from u_data_ex limit 2", null);
    RowSet results = cliServiceClient.fetchResults(operationHandle);

    for (Object[] result : results) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(result));
    }
```

### Embedded Mode (no external server)

```
    HiveConf hiveConf = new HiveConf();
    hiveConf.addResource("/Users/tzp/ppppathh/hive-site.xml");
    hiveConf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://localhost:9000");

    EmbeddedThriftBinaryCLIService service = new EmbeddedThriftBinaryCLIService();
    service.init(hiveConf);

    ICLIService icliService = service.getService();
    SessionHandle sessionHandle = icliService.openSession(USERNAME, PASSWORD, null);

    OperationHandle operationHandle = icliService.executeStatement(sessionHandle, "select * from u_data_ex limit 2", null);
    RowSet results = icliService.fetchResults(operationHandle);

    for (Object[] result : results) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(result));
    }
```

> This question is really old, but I still need some solutions, but there isn't any useful info at google/so/hive wiki, so I dive into the source code and find these.

All based on Hive 3.1.2.

Reference:

- org.apache.hive.service.server.HiveServer2
- org.apache.hive.service.cli.CLIServiceTest
- org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.ThriftCLIServiceTest